# Symfony 4 Accessing Swift_Mailer in Service

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, symfony4

I have been looking at the Symfony 4.1 documentation on using the Swift_mailer. However, it appears the documentation is only assumed it being used in the Controller classes. I'm trying to create a Service with some reusable functions that send email.

I created a EmailService.php file in my service directory. When creating a new instance of this service, it quickly throws and error:

> "Too few arguments to function
>   App\Service\EmailService::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   *MyApp\src\Controller\TestController.php on line 33
>   and exactly 1 expected"

I'm not sure how to pass \Swift_Mailer $mailer into the __construct correctly? I have auto wiring enabled in the services.yaml, so i'm not sure what I need to do differently?

```
class EmailService
{
    private $from = 'support@******.com';
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }
```

How do I pass the \Swift_Mailer into this EmailService construct?

I tried adding this to my config\services.yaml with no success:

```
App\Service\EmailService:
        arguments: ['@mailer']
```

Comment: And how are you trying to access your EmailService?  I suspect you are trying to new it.

Comment: Correct, "new EmailService()"

Comment: Please use either [Constructor injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#constructor-injection) or inject the service into your action by just adding it as argument to the method e.g. `public function index(Request $request, EmailService $emailService) {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by dbrumann in a comment, I needed to follow the proper way of injecting services.

**First**, I needed to add the services to config/services.yaml

```
#config/services.yaml
emailservice:
    class: App\Service\EmailService
    arguments: ['@swiftmailer.mailer.default', '@twig']
    public: true
```

**Second**, I need to setup the service to accept both the mailer, and twig for rendering the template.

```
#App/Service/EmailService.php
<?php
namespace App\Service;

class EmailService
{
    private $from = 'support@*****.com';
    private $mailer;
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig\Environment $templating)
    {
        $this->mailer       = $mailer;
        $this->templating   = $templating;
    }
   public function userConfirmation(string $recipient, string $confCode) : bool
   {

        $message = (new \Swift_Message())
        ->setSubject('Some sort of string')
        ->setFrom($this->from)
        ->setTo($recipient)
        ->setBody(
            $this->templating->render(
                'email/UserConfirmation.html.twig',
                array('confCode' => $confCode)
            ),
            'text/html'
        )
        /*
         * If you also want to include a plaintext version of the message
        ->addPart(
            $this->renderView(
                'emails/UserConfirmation.txt.twig',
                array('confCode' => $confCode)
            ),
            'text/plain'
        )
        */
    ;
    return $this->mailer->send($message);
  }
}
```

**Third**, to call it from the controller, make sure your controller is extending **Controller** and not the **AbstractController**! Crucial step!! Here is an example based on the parameters I require in my service:

```
public function userConfirmation()
{
     $emailService   = $this->get('emailservice');
     $sent = $emailService->userConfirmation('some@emailaddress.com', '2ndParam');
     return new Response('Success') //Or whatever you want to return
 }
```

I hope this helps people. AbstractController does not give you the proper access to the service containers.

Answer (score -1):

```
#config/services.yaml

    App\Service\EmailService
        arguments: ['@swiftmailer.mailer.default']
        public: true
```

And in your controller :

```
public function userConfirmation(EmailService $emailService)
{    
     $sent = $emailService->userConfirmation('some@emailaddress.com', '2ndParam');
     return new Response('Success') //Or whatever you want to return
 }
```

Use FQCN "App\Service\MyService" to declare services in services.yaml and a proper legacy_aliases.yaml file to declare legacy aliases like "app.service.my.service" it helps keep your services.yaml clean...